# Json encode array from PHP to populate in specific html id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am working in a form which actually works, and sends an email. At the end it shows in the html the message that it was successfully sent, but I want that message to be added to a specific id on my html. My last piece of code in my php is

```html
if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Problem in server php.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'thanks  '.$user_name .' for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
```

Then I want the output of either error or success to be add to a specific html id. My coding in jquery is:

```
 $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
    if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
      output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
    }else{
          $('#aniconf').removeClass('confcir').addClass('confcir2');
          output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
          //reset values in all input fields
          $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 

    }
    $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

Comment: What element are you trying to target? What happens now? Not really enough information given

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am trying to get the $output  to be inserted in the id 
<p id="here" > </p> 
Right now the output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
works but it put it outside, I want to put the response.text inside of the P id='here'

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please update question with more details. Expected behavior, current behavior etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part `$("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();` to

```
$('#here').html(output);
```

Comment: yes , I remove that part, but even when the form send the email correctly, it still doesnt get the message (not appear) on the id.
From the "else" condition, I want to use the "output" and put it inside of the <p id="here'></p>